# How to change Labels and Table View from another Class?

Tags: swift, uitableview, label

I made an application, this application have a couple of functions. It has `Table View`, `Labels`, `Buttons` etc. I made a `Picker View` in a class called `SettingsViewController` that is useful for choosing language. I made it and it's working good but I don't know how to change text of `Table View` and `Labels` of other classes. I'm not to experienced in calling classes.

This is my class `SettingsViewController`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

var languages = ["English", "German", "French"]

var selectedLanguage = 0

@IBOutlet var languageLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var topPartView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var languagePicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var SubmitLanguageButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func pickLanguageButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Show Picker
    topPartView.hidden = false
    languagePicker.hidden = false
    SubmitLanguageButton.hidden = false
}

@IBAction func submitLanguageButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Hidde Picker
    topPartView.hidden = true
    languagePicker.hidden = true
    SubmitLanguageButton.hidden = true

    if (selectedLanguage == 0) {
       languageLabel.text = "English"
    }
    else if (selectedLanguage == 1) {
       languageLabel.text = "German"
    }
    else if (selectedLanguage == 2) {
       languageLabel.text = "French"
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    topPartView.hidden = true
    languagePicker.hidden = true
    SubmitLanguageButton.hidden = true

    languagePicker.delegate = self
    languagePicker.dataSource = self

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return languages[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return languages.count
}

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
public func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    selectedLanguage = row
}
}
```

Another random `ViewController` with `Table View` and `Label`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let foodList:[String] = ["Apple", "Bread", "Phineapple", "Water", "Other"]

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet var foodTitleLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    foodTitleLabel.text = "Food"

    myTableView.reloadData()

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var returnValue = 0

    return returnValue
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCells", forIndexPath: indexPath)


    myCell.textLabel!.text = foodList[indexPath.row]
    myCell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
    return myCell
}
}
```

So how I'm gonna change `Labels` and `Table View` from another class, because every text have to be on language that is chose in `SettingsViewController` ? 
For ex: When user choose English, the text in all `ViewController`s have to be in English.
When user choose French, the text in all `ViewController`s have to be in French.

If this question was not clear, please inform me, I wil try to show more info. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Just some advice, you dont need to post nearly as much code as you did. Your TableViewController's `numberOfRowsInSection` method isn't relevant to your question, for example.

Comment: Ya I know, but I did so because I want others to se that is working good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. First of All the variable `selectedLanguage` I declared it out of the class `SettingsViewController`.

```
import UIKit

var selectedLanguage = 0 //<<< Here

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

var languages = ["English", "German", "French"]
```

After that I did this in method `viewDidLoad` to every `ViewController` (I will show just one `ViewController`).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    if (selectedLanguage == 0) { //English
        foodTitleLabel.text = "Food"
        foodList = ["Apple", "Bread", "Pineapple", "Water", "Other"]
    }
    else if (selectedLanguage == 1) { //German
        foodTitleLabel.text = "Lebensmittel"
        foodList = [ "Apfel", "Brot", "Pineapple", "Wasser","Andere"]
    }
    if (selectedLanguage == 2) { //French
        foodTitleLabel.text = "Aliments"
        foodList = ["Pomme", "Pain", "Ananas", "Eau", "Autre"]
    }
```

I hope this will be helpful for other users, because It worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Adding global state is a bit of a weak response.  If you're really interested in making your application international then you should learn https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

Comment: Ya, I almost did that before several months, but I had to use something else. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: If you're looking to pass values between ViewControllers then you should use the prepareForSegue method.  You can then access the segue.destinationViewController and pass values through.  What I then do is also set a callback method which I use to write the value back onto the source controller.

Answer (score 3):

We can accomplish this in a cleaner way with less code like :

```
enum names{
case English, German, French
func food() -> String {
    switch self {
     case English: return "food"
     case German: return "Lebensmittel"
     case French: return "Aliments"
    }
 }

func foodList() -> [] {
    switch self {
     case English: return ["Apple", "Bread", "Pineapple", "Water", "Other"]
     case German: return [ "Apfel", "Brot", "Pineapple", "Wasser","Andere"]
     case French: return ["Pomme", "Pain", "Ananas", "Eau", "Autre"]
    }
 }
}

import UIKit

var lang = names.English

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    foodTitleLabel.text = lang.food()
    foodList = lang.foodList()
```

Answer (score 2):

So you could address by different approachs the problem, but for my point of view the easiest one is to implement a protocol that handles events in a viewcontroller and has an impact in another one for examlple

```
protocol ChangeLanguagesProtocol
{
   func returnNewLanguages(newlanguages:[String])
}
```

then you you will need to implement the protocol and its method in your viewcontroller like

```
  class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, 
  UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource , ChangeLanguagesProtocol {


  var languages = ["English", "German", "French"]

  func returnNewLanguages(newlanguages:[String]){
       self.languages = newlanguages
  }
```

Then in you second ViewController class you need to have a var of the type of your protocol and trigger its method when your need it

```
  //variable
  var delegate:ChangeLanguagesProtocol!

  //for example when clicking a button 
  @IBAction func SampleButtonPress(sender:UIButton){

  let newlanguages:[String] = ["Spanish", "Chinesse", "German", "French", "Other"]
      delegate.returnNewLanguages(newlanguages)
  }
```

last step we need to assign the delegate variable when we are going to push to the desired viewcontroller, in the case where viewcontrollers are not next to each other you can use singleton or a shared instance to maintain your delegate property until you need it, but it will look something like

```
// this should be in your first ViewController
  @IBAction func gotoNextViewController(sender:UIButton){

    let _localization = Localization(nibName: "Localization", bundle:nil)
    _localization .delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(_localization , animated: true)
  }
```

Comment: this is another approach you can use

Comment: Yes, But how I'm gonna change `Labels` and other stuff ? It's not clear.

Comment: So, the point is, When `submitLanguageButton` is pressed, the language of (`Labels` and `Text`) in other `ViewController`s to be changed. Not to add more languages.

Comment: you just need to change the method signature and parameters for example instead of calling the method returnNew Languages you can have  
    returnValues(labelstext:String)'

and when you are implementing the protocol in your first class you just assign the parameter to the label that you want 

    returnValues(labeltext:String)
    {
         label.text = labeltext
    }'

Comment: Thanks my friend, but I found solution. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to internationalize your app. Apple has some built in stuff for this that you should check out: https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

If that doesn't suit your needs, to answer your question, your views should set their text when they either load (viewDidLoad) or right before they appear (viewWillAppear) as a result of the user's language choice, which could possibly be stored in NSUserDefaults. Your settings class shouldn't have to force any change in other views, your other views should set their own text to the right language before they are displayed.

```
struct Localization {

    static func stringsForScreen(screenName:String, forLanguage language:String) -> [String:String] {
        //parse a file that has the strings for the given screen in the given language, and return it
    }
}

class HomeViewController:UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel:UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var bodyLabel:UILabel?

    override func viewDidLoad() { //or possibly viewDidAppear, depends on your needs
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let language = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("currentLanguage") ?? "English"

        let textDict = Localization.stringsForScreen("HomeViewController" forLanguage:language)

        titleLabel.text = textDict["titleLabelText"] ?? ""
        bodyLabel.text = textDict["bodyLabelText"] ?? ""
    }
}

class PickLanguageViewController:UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var languages = ["English","French","Spanish"]
    //Whatever method the picker uses
    func pickerView(pickerView:UIPickerView didSelectRow row:Int inComponent component:Int) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(languages[row] forKey:"currentLanguage")
    }
}
```

skeleton example of how this might be structured.

Comment: Yes, actually my App is localized but, I don't like this, because the language of app will be as the language of iPhone. So this doesn't suit. what about other method, can you explain more how I have to do that ?

Comment: Well you would need to build your own code to handle getting the correct text for the given language for a page. Then in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, you would request the text for that page, and it would return a dictionary or something with all the text in the correct language. You would then set all visible text to be the correct bit of the text in the dictionary.

Comment: @EminEmini I added a skeleton example of how it might look. the rest is up to you.

Comment: I dont understand your question. You don't have to access your UI elements from any class other than the class that owns them in the example that I have given.

Comment: Please see edit for how you would set the language from one view controller, and have it use that picked language in the other view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107779/discussion-between-will-m-and-emin-emini).